# In jquery How to tell what form is being submitted?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have ajax calls made like this:

```
$('.register a').click(register);
```

The register function:

```
function register(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var params = $('.register').serialize();
    Api.callApi(
        "/api/authkey/create_user",
        params,
        //success!
        function(response){
            settooltip(response.msg[0])
            // GA
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/registered']);
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'register', 'public']);
        },
        //error
        function(response){
            settooltip(response.msg[0])
        }
    );
}
```

Sometimes ajax responds with errors. I try to show theese arrows next the field that has the error(that's what the settooltipc–function does). However, the api only responds with the name of the field that has the error, and sometimes, there are more fields than one with the same name. This means I can't know what field I should apply the error message to.

My Idea for how to solve this is by setting an ID to the form that was latest submitted. However, I would like to do this within the register-function. I could use "this" if someone actually clicks the .register a, but if they use enter, "this" contain the window-element instead. Is this a good approach? In that case, how can I tell what form is being submitted?

Comment: If you did all of your work from the submit event rather than click, `this` would always be the form.

Comment: Expanding on what @KevinB said, take a look at [the documentation with examples](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Comment: Shouldn't `$(this).parent().attr("id")` work (since the function is being called from the form child anchor?)

Comment: I'm missing some context: You have several forms in your document that can be submitted. But with `$('.register a').click(register);` you're setting a handler for `<a>` elements (that are descendants of elements with class `register`). What's the connection?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the form's sumbit event, not the click on anything to process form submission.

```
$("#the-form").submit(register);
```

Also, with jQuery, you can just `return false;` at the end of the event handler. It does the same thing as `e.preventDefault();` but in a cross-browser way.

And if you need to manually cause the form to be submitted (and hence your event handler to be executed), you can still do something like this:

```
$('.register a').click(function() {$("#the-form").submit();});
```

This way, `this` will always be the form in the "submit" event handler.